# URL regex matching port and dash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this url regex matching almost everything i need (port include), but excluding dash.

The regex:

```
/^(http|https):\/\/\w+(\.\w+)*(:[0-9]+)?\/?(\/[.\w]*)*$/
```

I want to include the possibility to have dash on it, but i don't achieve to do that.
I tried to change .\w to -\w. but it does not seems to work.

Does anyone know how to include dash on it ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far, example input and example output.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your pattern like that (I have removed all capture groups):

```
/^https?:\/\/\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/\w+(?:[\/.-]\w+)*)?\/?$/
```

But keep in mind that the URL syntax can be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Dashes need to be escaped in a Regex : `\-`, because they can appear in this syntax : `[0-9]`

Comment: It only needs to be escaped inside a character class except at first or last position.